# Is it possible to hack GTK to render to OpenGL texture

Tags: opengl, gtk

I'm writing an OpenGL game, and want native looking GUI elements. I was wondering if anyone has successfully hacked GTK+ using `GtkOffscreenWindow` and `gtk_offscreen_window_get_pixbuf` to render to an OpenGL texture, and whether this would have reasonable performance, considering repeated re-uploading of texture data every time the GUI is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is certainly possible, I'd instead use a real OpenGL widget toolkit like Clutter. If you want to render GTK+ with OpenGL, I'd start by creating a new GDK backend (X11/OpenGL or something like that), that (re-)implements all the GDK drawing functions using OpenGL. A nice side effect would be, that all GTK+ windows would allow for ordinary OpenGL rendering, too, i.e. no more need for a GtkGLWidget class.

Comment: So to render GTK+ to an OpenGL context I'd have to write a new GDK backend?

Comment: If you want it to be really transparent usable and not litter your application's code with workarounds and hacks, yes.